# How can I resize a textbox to fill the area of a jQuery UI Dialog?

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-ui

I have a dialog with just the one text box inside.

```
<div id="commonDialog" style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; height: 560px;" 
              scrolltop="0" scrollleft="0">
```

How can I resize a textbox that's inside of the DIV so it fills the dialog box? I have to do this in Open event of the dialog as there is some logic that says if it is needed or not in there. I was able to resize like this but I am not sure how to do it with the dialog's variable width.

```
 $('#TextBox1').css({'height': 400 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do this by using a percentage `width` on the `input`:

```css
#Textbox1 { width: 90%; }
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/8KafJ/

---

If you need to set the `width` on `open`, you should be able to write something like:

```
$("#commonDialog").dialog({
    open: function () {
        $("#Textbox1").css("width", "90%");
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/TUJ3Y/

Comment: The problem is that sometimes I need it to fill the window and other times not. So I need some way to dynamically set this up in the open event of the window. I tried this but it does not seem to take css percentage values. Only pixel values

Answer (score 0):

You have to manage using css of input box.

Comment: But I don't know how to set to the correct size. I already confirmed I can change it. How can I find out the max width and height?